# A basic problem on fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Supose $f$ is a continuously diferentiable function. Then I need to prove that

$$\int_{a}^{b}|f'| \geq \sup_P\{\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})|\}$$ using fundamental theorem of calculus. I am able to do the other way proof using Mean Value theorem. $P$ stands for partition. So. sup P means supremum over all partitions.

Here is what I have tried : some how I have to get $f$ in place of $f'$ and also get rid of $|~~ |$ from $f$. So, I have to use antiderivative $F$ but $F'=|f'|$. So, how to proceed after that.

Comment: You need to write what $P$ is.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
|f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| = \left | \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} f'(t)dt \right | \leq \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} |f'|
$$
Now add up both sides.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=x_1 <\cdots<x_{n+1}=b$, then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n|f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)|=\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}f'(t)\,dt\right|\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}|f'(t)|\,dt=\int_{a}^{b}|f'(t)|\,dt
$$

Answer (score 0):

So Let P be {a = x(0), x(1),...., x(n) = b} be any partition of [a, b]. Then we have:
/f(x(k) - f(x(k-1))/ = /Int(x(k-1) to x(k)) of f'(x)dx/ <= Int(x(k-1) to x(k)) of /f'(x)/ dx ( read: the absolute of the integral of f from m to n is less than or equal to the integral of the absolute of f from m to n ). So the sum from k = 1 to n less than or equal to Sigma (k = 1 to n ) of Integral (x(k-1) to x(k)) of /f'(x)/dx = integral( a to b ) of /f'(x)/dx. Since this is true for all P's the conclusion follows.